# What is the best way to trim old rhododendrons? How far back should I cut them?

Tags: pruning, rhododendrons

What is the best way to cut old rhododendrons back and much should I cut?

Answer (score 2):

**Pruning Techniques**

One hack in pruning **overgrown shrubs** is to remove a third of the limbs at a time to the ground, over 3 years, for completely renewed ground growth. Angle your cuts so no stubs show from the front.

**Or**,  you can prune a foot or two off every branch.

**Timing**

Be aware that rhododendron, like azalea, set their buds in the Fall. So you are saying goodbye to some flowering if you prune in the Winter or Spring. Still, you can prune anytime with this loss of flowers in mind. But waiting to prune when buds show color will allow you to gather bouquets for indoor arrangements in water.